# Vertex Group Not Being Recognize for Reference

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-groups

I am a newbie in Blender, I'm trying to follow a donut tutorial in Youtube. Already on the part on modeling the sprinkles. Below are the steps

- Went to weighted paint mode
- start targeting the area I want to have sprinkles
- I went to Data Object Properties to Rename the Vertex Group

[image]

- I went back to Object Mode then to Geometry Workspace
- I have Expose DENSITY of 'DISTRIBUTE POINTS ON FACES' value to GROUP INPUT
  [image]
  [image]
- This is where I am facing the challenge. Whenever I click on the 'reference/attribute' button beside Density, the vertex group from my weighted is not appearing. I tried typing the name but it is not showing anything

[image]
[image]

How can I see the vertex groups I created?

Is there anything I need to trigger in Blender to show the groups?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using version 3.2 or above, you can use [`Named Attribute Node`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/geometry_nodes/input/named_attribute.html) right inside the node tree. Attributes not appearing can be a bug or just a temporal malfunction. Maybe restarting Blender can help. This happens sometimes where features are not doing the right thing but can be resolved by restarting Blender in most cases. If it still does not work [report the bug to Blender](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Bug_Reports).